# Windows Server Backup is installed but not selectable anywhere

Tags: windows-server-backup, windows-server-2019

On a Server 2019 box Windows Server Backup is installed

[image]

But it's not available for selection within the usual suspects?

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to get it to appear?

Thanks

Comment: i suggest not to use this function, use free veeam

Comment: We do also use AOMEI Backupper, but that crashes the Server when setting scheduled backups. Windows Server Backup is useful because restoring is generic and has no issues with schedules backups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that installing Network Load Balancing enables Window Server Backup.

If you are connected via RDP it will drop the connection, then come back up again, during installation.

If you are running Domino Server on the box you are installing Load Balancing on, Domino Console will disconnect and need to be restarted.

Other than the two noted caveats above Windows Server Backup does now appear in Admin Tools

I would note that we do have several Server 2016 and Server 2019 boxes and this is the first time I have encountered this issue.

Comment: to be honestly this is a bug, ive seen boxes with 16/19 whcich dont have it selected but it was truly working installed and in use even we dont suggest it